# Improving context-based search

Tags: java, wordnet

I was looking at the possibility of implementing a context-based search for  a single word using WordNet. The idea is this:

The user searches for virus, it should return the contexts / applications of the searched word, which in our case are health and computing. The user now selects the context, which now retrieves the meaning based on the context selected. I have been checking at the possibility of using WordNet but it seems WordNet does not have this capability. I also looked at word sense disambiguation but then its for sentence not a word. How do I achieve this? Is there any dictionary capable of achieving this? Any idea on other work around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve this, I got this project called extended wordnet domain (XWN) http://adimen.si.ehu.es/web/XWND.

According to the authors, "is an ongoing work aiming to automatically improve WordNet Domains", Wordnet domains is another project that serves the same purpose as XWN but limited to wordnet 2.0 dictionary files. XWN works with Wordnet 3.0 I have tested it but I couldn't figure out the criteria for selecting the appropriate domain for a word. Another issue is loading the domains with the offsets in memory takes a lot of time. This is because the whole offsets in each domains is about 19 million. And also XWN contains about 180 domains. Each domain has the same words in them but for different weights.

For example, a word let say virus could has a weight of 0.00007899 in computer_science, and 0.08766 in biology, and 7.9866 in acoustics, and 4.97655 in law just like that. I also observed that the weights are in ascending order and the first few words in each domain are closely related to that domain. So I managed to use it but less optimally because I have not figured the criteria of selecting the domains but for all domains are selected and retrieves meaning for only the ones related to the searched word.

I hope this helps someone, and someone figure the criteria I talked about. But for now I proposed improving Wordnet Domain http://wndomains.fbk.eu in the same direction the authors used which is matching a word with a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Disambiguation is a big computational problem. If you're willing to do something relatively simple I would point you to [BabelNet](http://babelnet.org) and [Babelfy](http://babelfy.org).

The first one is a huge encyclopedic dictionary, the second is a disambiguation system developed by the BabelNet team.

With BabelNet you have several metadata about the word like Categories and it also have a Java API. Maybe you can work something out of it.

Also, I would recommend you to try several text analytics software like [MeaningCloud](https://www.meaningcloud.com/es/)

Comment: You seem like you have quite a lot of knowledge on this. Can you please elaborate more? I am also working on a similar problem and would like to know more.

Comment: @Ahmedov What exactly would you like to know? What are you working on?

Comment: I am working on a big corpus of datasets. Basically my problem is to find "needle in a haystack". That's why I need a good disambiguation algorithm, as well as some synonym finding approaches.

Comment: @Ahmedov Well, supervised disambiguation algorithms tend to obtain the best results BUT they are based on annotated examples that are not always available. When you do not have large training datasets you can rely on Knowledge Based approaches. These are based on large dictionaries like BabelNet. Also, for synonyms BabelNet works very well because of the way the knowledges is structured. Maybe you can ask a more detailed separated question and I can explain a little better.

Comment: @aquiros thanks for your suggestion but when i looked through babelnet i saw almost 16gb file for offline use. Was disappointed, then i got extended wordnet domain, a list of wordnet offsets with their weight for each category (domain)